# How to test drag and drop with React Dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dnd

I created a drag and drop interaction in React using `react-dnd` library and I want to **test** that on drop, a certain function is called.

However, I'm blocked on how to setup the test in order to make it pass.

My code until now is:

```
it('should ', () => {
      const dropTarget = mountWithTheme(
        withRedux(store, <DnDCard fileId={folder._id} onClick={onClick} />),
      )

      const dragSource = mountWithTheme(
        withRedux(store, <DnDCard fileId={img._id} onClick={onClick} />)
      )

      var backend = getBackendFromInstance(<DnDCard fileId={folder._id} onClick={onClick} /> )
      var manager = backend.manager

      simulateDragDropSequence(dropTarget.instance(), dragSource.instance(), backend)
    })
```

And in that `simulateDragDropSequence` I get an error saying that:

> `Cannot read property 'getHandlerId' of null`.

That's because the `function` tries to call `getHandlerId` on the first 2 parameters of it, but apparently the instance doesn't provide that.

That `mountWithTheme` is adding `Redux` with a `Provider` for our component so it works fine.

What would be the issue here?

LE: Read [here](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drop-target) that `getHandlerId` is an instance method available when setting up the component with Legacy Decorator API but I did it using Hooks ( Top-Level API ). I think this might be the reason this is not quite testable.

Comment: I was looking at the [react-dnd/dnd-core](https://github.com/react-dnd/dnd-core/blob/v1.1.0/src/__tests__/DragDropManager-test.js.) UTs and saw they were simulating the drag and drop like so:

```backend.simulateBeginDrag([sourceId]);
        backend.simulateDrop();
        backend.simulateEndDrag(sourceId);``` I can not find any references to `simulateDragDropSequence` being used in the UTs

Comment: Yep, that's because that's a function that I found in the `utils.js` file from `react-dnd-test-utils` package.

Comment: Were you able to ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem right now.

Comment: @AndrewGarrison I don't have access to that code anymore but someone in my team did it by mocking useDrag and useDrop custom hooks and then using those on the components.